# 'Slide-out' animation class not being applied on click

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, css-transitions

Right now I am in a predicament where I've created a full screen navigation that applies the `bounce-in-top` class on click.

Once menu toggle button is clicked again, it is supposed to remove the `bounce-in-top` class and instead add the `slide-out-top` class to trigger that exit animation.

If I click anywhere on the navigation overlay, the menu successfully applies the class and slides off the screen. However, if I press my toggle button, the class is not applied and just abruptly leaves the screen.

I am scratching my head as to why this is happening.

Here is my Codepen code: https://codepen.io/jayciemota/pen/GRmpbxZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class isn't applied because you aren't adding it.

```
  if (clickEd) {
    navMenu.classList.remove('slide-out-top')
    navMenu.classList.toggle('bounce-in-top')
    menuToggle.classList.toggle('clicked')
  }
```

Ideally you should add `.slide-out-top` the every other time the menu toggle is clicked. You can do this by simply checking if the toggle has been clicked before and closing it if it has.

```
   if (clickEd) {
     if (menuToggle.classList.contains('clicked')) {
      menuToggle.classList.remove('clicked');
      navMenu.classList.remove('bounce-in-top')
      navMenu.classList.toggle('slide-out-top')
     } else {
      navMenu.classList.remove('slide-out-top')
      navMenu.classList.toggle('bounce-in-top')
      menuToggle.classList.toggle('clicked') 
     }
```

[result](https://jsfiddle.net/2njc0sut/)

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I didn’t think to add a condition to check if ‘clicked’ was being applied. The only other thing I noticed is that if double-click or double-tap anywhere outside of the toggle button, it still triggers the exit animation and applies the slide-out-top class. Not sure how to remove this so it only works when clicking toggle button.